# php what is the advantage of regenerating a session id like in codeigniter sess_time_to_update

Tags: php, codeigniter, sessionid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is regenerating the session id after login a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136240/is-regenerating-the-session-id-after-login-a-good-practice)

What is the advantage of regenerating a session id like in codeigniter.

Codeigniter uses its option sess_time_to_update to set the interval to regenerate session id.

Answer (score 2):

Well the main advantage is from security perspective to prevent the 'session lock' by an attacker and minimize the window of attack for him.